# How to go back to parent screen in react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

#### Problem

```
RootTabNavigator
    | Auth Screen
    | Welcome Screen
    | MainTabNavigator 
              | FeedStacknavigator
                       | Screen A

              | MenuStackNavigator 
                       | Screen B <-I'm here and want to reset to 'Auth Screen'
```

The tree structure shows my app's Navigation structure. I'm on 'Screen B' and would like to go back to Auth Screen. (NOT Navigate) When I navigate to Auth Screen, it create new Auth Screen and I want to avoid it.

```
if ( ... ) {
      // I'm getting undefined error here
      nextProps.navigation.reset('Autho');
```

Why is it not working?

#### Possible Solution1: reset

```
  const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [
          // getting error because auth screen is not in MenuStacknavigator. 
          NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Auth'})
      ]
  })
  this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

#### Possible Solution #2 :

```
  const backAction = NavigationActions.back({
    key: 'Autho'
  })
  # Back Action doesn't do anything
  this.props.navigation.dispatch(backAction); # not working
```

#### Possible Solution #3 :

dispatch custom action. <- there were some solutions for StackNavigator but in my case it's TabNavigator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please feel free to answer. I've found a simple solution for now :

```
const backAction = NavigationActions.back({
    key: null
})
nextProps.navigation.dispatch(backAction);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930049/how-to-reset-all-screens-when-user-logs-out-scroll-and-page-index

Comment: Awesome.It worked even with new react navigation version

Answer (score 1):

To reset to the start, I usually use:

```
NavigationActions.reset({
    index: 0, 
    actions: []
)
```

---

As an aside, a better navigation structure would be to have multiple tab navigators that you switch out depending on the auth state. In your case that would be something like an `AuthTabNavigator` and a `MainTabNavigator`, that you can switch between.

Hope this helps!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930049/how-to-reset-all-screens-when-user-logs-out-scroll-and-page-index

Comment: I think you can solve this problem (+200 bounty) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930049/how-to-reset-tabnavigator-when-user-logs-out-from-other-screen